# Remote git repo or archive ERROR: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined lando

Tags: git, drupal, lando

I'm setting up Lando with Drupal and have a problem with
remote git-repo or archive ERROR ==> Cannot read property 'split' of undefined.

Can someone help please ?

```
PS C:\Users\USER> cd ..

PS C:\Users> cd ..

PS C:\> cd local

PS C:\local> lando init

? From where should we get your app's codebase? (Use arrow keys)


> current working directory

  github

  lagoon

  pantheon

  platformsh
```

Remote git repo or archive ERROR ==> Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the latest docker and then Lando? If you did, uninstall Docker and re-run the Lando install and install the version of docker that lando is bundled with, this seams to be a bug on windows with the latest version of docker.